# Open pdf from android app with acrobat reader

Tags: java, android, mobile, acrobat

I am trying launch a pdf to open in Acrobat Reader from my app.  I copied this code from the Adobe Mobile developer site but it crashes my app and does not start the reader.  Any ideas what I am doing wrong?

```
package com.example.zoot;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import android.content.ActivityNotFoundException;
import android.content.ComponentName;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;

import com.github.barteksc.pdfviewer.PDFView;
import com.github.barteksc.pdfviewer.listener.OnRenderListener;
import com.github.barteksc.pdfviewer.scroll.DefaultScrollHandle;

import java.io.File;

public class Activity2 extends AppCompatActivity {
PDFView pdfview;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_2);

        File f = new File("src/main/assets/j_theme1.pdf");
        Intent i = new Intent();
        i.setAction(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
        i.setData(Uri.fromFile(f));
        i.setComponent(new ComponentName("com.adobe.reader", "com.adobe.reader.AdobeReader"));
        try
        {
            startActivity(i);
        }
        catch (ActivityNotFoundException e)
        {
            Log.i("App_Tag","Exception - "+e.getMessage());
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: The only exceptions are:
2021-08-24 11:50:42.960 2247-2247/? E/IpcDispatcher<0>: SecChannelProxy getService/setCallback: java.util.NoSuchElementException
2021-08-24 11:50:43.078 1926-1926/? E/ExpandableNotifRow: onNotificationUpdated() NSSL is null..

and I have no idea what that means

Comment: The logcat will also indicate the code lines that cause the exception. Please post more lines from the logcat in a code block in your post. Dont use a comment for that.

Comment: `File f = new File("src/main/assets/j_theme1.pdf")` You use a file path that cannot exist on an Android device. Please check using f.exists(). And if you put the file at designtime in assets folder than you can certainly not use the File class.

Comment: You will have a FileUriExposedException too.

Comment: If I download the pdf into my downloads directory what would the correct path be?  I can't seem to find a straightforward answer

Comment: The actual correct path depends on what you consider to be 'your downloads directory'. But... How does your app manage to download to download directory if it does not know the path? I'm puzzled.

Comment: Sorry for not being clear.  I was thinking as another alternative I could put the pdfs in the download directory on the devices and have the Acrobat app launch them from there so they do not need to be in the assets folder in the app.

Comment: Yes, everything is possible.